# Laravel login with multiple username choice

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication, inertiajs

I want to add the possibility to login by username and registration number to my laravel vuejs application. I was able to do it by changing username function in  `/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticateUsers.php`

But whenever I clone the project from github I've got to change it again since vendor directory is in gitignore file.

Here is the code that I changed in username function

```
public function username()
    {
        $field = (filter_var(request()->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !request()->email) ? 'email' : 'username';
        if($field != 'email')
            $field = is_numeric(request()->email) ? 'matricule' : 'username';
        request()->merge([$field => request()->email]);
        return $field;
    }
```

I want to change that function once and forever and push it to my github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying in `vendor folder` you can `override` in `LoginController` .
Just add same method in `LoginController`.Make sure to import `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in `LoginController`

```
public function username()
{
        $field = (filter_var(request()->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !request()->email) ? 'email' : 'username';
        if($field != 'email')
            $field = is_numeric(request()->email) ? 'matricule' : 'username';
        request()->merge([$field => request()->email]);
        return $field;
}
```

FullCode

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = "/dashboard";

  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        $field = (filter_var(request()->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !request()->email) ? 'email' : 'username';
        if($field != 'email')
            $field = is_numeric(request()->email) ? 'matricule' : 'username';
        request()->merge([$field => request()->email]);
        return $field;
    }
}
```